# How to update a zipped file's last write time just after it has been zipped using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am very new to Powershell. I have a code that would Zip files from Folder 1 to Folder 2 and update the last Write time of the zipped files to that of the original file.

My code would work in this flow: **Zip all the files-->Update all files' last Write Time.**

However I want this flow:

**Zip 1st file->Update it-->Zip 2nd file-->Update it-->Zip Nth file-->Update it.**

I have tried many things. However my code fails while updating just after the file is created. This is the error I get when the update code executes:

> Cannot index into a null array.

When I execute the code a second time after all files are created, the code works (Essentially making it flow like I previously mentioned).

Can anyone please have a look at my code and inform if this can be done?

```
$oldzipfiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder1
$newzipfiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder2
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder1
$i = 0;

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    #Zipping files
    Set-Location $Folder1;
    $Zipname = $File.Basename + ".zip";
    Zip $Folder2\$Zipname $File;

    #Updating LastWriteTime
    $newzipfiles[$i].LastWriteTime = $oldzipfiles[$i].LastWriteTime;

    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Difficult to read that code. Can you add some indentation - it's not clear at all.

Comment: I hope this is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the answer.

```
$oldzipfiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder1; $newzipfiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder2;
```

These lines must come inside the foreach loop.. The code works :)